Making many div blocks in html without css
I am trying to make this  in html as different divs. I am trying to make it work but i keep getting stuck because the code is getting too complex and honestly i have no idea how to make this work so providing the code is of no use im just trying to see if this can be made solely using html or do we have to use flex or something for it.
I tried making div families like this

    
        
        
        
    
this is just a part i got stuck after this as the new divs keep overlapping each other I have tried the float property and the position one too. HELP!!!

In your question you don't even have what you have tried to do. Anyways, to shorten your pain something like this is practically impossible without using CSS. HTML is HTML (Hyper Text Markup Language) and elements in it can either be inline or block level elements. You can try using tables, but it would be far away from desired layout. So, to conclude just use CSS and that's it.

yeah i had to use inline css but i did it today this was actually just too see if this question can be done without css or not

CSS is the only way to do this, but don't worry, it's not too complicated.
If the whole page is going to be centered, put everything into one div and put "style="width: 100%; margin: auto;" on it.
Divide the big sidebar and the other content using divs:
<div class="sidebar">
   contents here
</div>
<div class="content">
   more divs here
</div>

For an easier route, you could use tables to make the page and insert the content there.

thank  you!! i had to style the divs too because they are literally transparent using just html so using divs plus styling with inline css did the job  easily in minutes
